# Is there a way to update specific dependency according to package.json changes?

Tags: node.js, npm, web-deployment, package.json

I am writing deployment scripts for my application on AWS. I created an AMI and it will run following scripts after boot.

```
cd $APP_DIR
git pull
npm install
npm start
```

It works alright until I updated some of my dependencies (e.g. React v0.12 -> v0.14). It looks like `npm install` will not update the module that already installed.

Currently I have two options:

- Add `rm -rf node_modules` before `npm install`, but it is really expensive in booting phase.
- Every time existing dependency updated, create a new AMI. Obviously annoying because then I have extra dumb work on update launch-profile and auto-scaling settings.

Is there an easier way to update modules only when their versions changed in `package.json`?

Comment: Try running `npm update`. Also this has nothing to do with AWS.

Comment: @MarkB Blame me. I didn't look deep into `npm update`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `npm update` to update all modules listed in package.json depending on [caret (^), tilde (~) or asterisk (*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343224/difference-between-tilde-and-caret-in-package-json) before their name.